# How to compare current time database stored times in android?

Tags: java, android, time

I am doing some train schedule application. I have stored trains and timings for their corresponding schedule. If I am selecting the particular train name I have to show the timings of that corresponding train. Now I have to compare my data base times with current time. My db time if after one hour of my current time means I have to store that into separate array and after 2 hours means I have to store that into separate array. And my code is here.

```
     ArrayList<String> str_arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> str_arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<Integer> hr_arr_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> mint_arr_1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> hr_arr_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> mint_arr_2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


     String str,str1;
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> new_item = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
 int[] str_int = new int[3];
 int[] str_int1 = new int[3];
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public class SheduleActivityMain extends Activity
   {
     int count=0;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar now1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar now2 = Calendar.getInstance();
   System.out.println("Current time : " + dateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
   String time_now = dateFormat.format(now.getTime());
   System.out.println("time_now----->"+time_now);
   now1.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);

   System.out.println("New time after adding 1 hours : "
                     + dateFormat.format(now1.getTime()));
   now2.add(Calendar.HOUR,2);

   System.out.println("New time after adding 2 hours : "
                     + dateFormat.format(now2.getTime()));
   System.out.println("Is now1 after now ? : " + now1.after(now));

   StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(time_now, ":");
   while (st1.hasMoreElements())
    {
        //System.out.println(st1.nextElement());
        str = (String) st1.nextElement();
        str_arr1.add(str);
    } 
        str_int[0] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr1.get(0));
       str_int[1] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr1.get(1));
       str_int[2] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr1.get(2));
     for(int j=0;j<str_int.length;j++)
        {
         System.out.println("integer array is... "+j+"..."+str_int[j]);
        }


       for(int time=0;time<train_time.length;time++)
       {

            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(train_time[time], ":");

            while (st2.hasMoreElements())
            {
                str1 = (String) st2.nextElement();
                str_arr2.add(str1);
                System.out.println("str1..."+str1);

            }   

            System.out.println("str_arr2.........."+str_arr2);
     System.out.println("method calling..........");

       getTrainTime(str_arr2.get(count),str_arr2.get(count+1));

       for(int chk=count;chk<=str_arr2.size()-3;chk++)
       {
           getTrainTime(str_arr2.get(count),str_arr2.get(count+1));
       }

}


    void getTrainTime(String s1,String s2)
    {
        System.out.println("count--->"+count);
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        System.out.println("n1.n2  "+n1+n2);
        count = count+3;
        System.out.println(str_int[0]+str_int[1]);
        if(n1==str_int[0]+1)
        {
            System.out.println("inside if condition.....");
            hr_arr_1.add(n1);
            //mint_arr_1.add(n2);
            System.out.println("hr_arr_1,mint_arr_1"+hr_arr_1+mint_arr_1);

        }
        else if(n1==str_int[0]+2 )
        {

        }
        //System.out.println("hr_arr_1,mint_arr_1"+hr_arr_1+mint_arr_1);

      }

 }
```

I got some error like this..

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12

How can I compare two times? How can I resolve this error? Can anybody help me?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How are you storing the times? You say you're storing it in some array "like this" - like what?

Comment: All we can say is: solve the problem like this.

Comment: Most descriptive variable's names ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12
```

This error means, you try to get the value at the 13th position, but you array has only 12 entries. (-> `Index ouf of bounds`). Keep in mind: Index of Array starts with 0!

You should use sth like `yourArray[yourArray.length - 1]`

**EDIT:**
And please modify your code next time. it`s unreadable (remove unnecessary System.out.print, give variables a describing name...)

By the way, to check if value is within the next two hours, you can use `Calendar` objects like

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar currentTimePlus2 = Calendar.getInstance();
currentTimePlus2.add(Calendar.HOUR,2);

Calendar yourDataTime; //where ever it might come

if( yourDataTime.getTime().before(currentTimePlus2.getTime()) && 
    yourDataTime.getTime().after(currentTime.getTime()){

    //your Data within the next two hours
} else{

   //your Data NOT within the next two hours
}
```

)